# "Не думать, чтобы" vs. "не думать, что"

Tags: синтаксис, союзы

Еще один глагол с союзом, от которого я totally confused.
**"не думать, чтобы" vs. "не думать, что"**

Искала в корпусе и заметила, что "не думать, что" превалирует, хотя и предложения с "не думать, чтобы" есть. 
Прошла почти через все примеры в корпусе, стараясь выявить принцип употребления "чтобы" и "что" после "не думать", но к сожалению не стала умнее.

Например:

> 1) **Не думаю, чтобы** жена **догадывалась** об измене.

(Здесь почти уверена можно "чтобы" субституировать через "что")

> 2) Сначала я **не думала, что** **должна отреагировать** на его маил, но потом
>   все-таки из вежливости ответила.

(Здесь русская девочка говорит, что "чтобы" не подходит абсолютно, но не может сказать почему).

Есть в них какая-то разница? Если в (1) они взаимоупотребляемые, значит семантически сходные? Почему тогда субституция в (2) невозможна? HELP!

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Спасибо большое Вам за ответы! Экстра спасибо за полезные линки!!!

Answer (score 2):

2) Сначала я не думала, что должна отреагировать на его маил,
       но потом все-таки из вежливости ответила.

Чтобы произвести мену союза, здесь нужно убрать слово "должна":
 Сначала я не думала, чтобы отреагировать на его маил,
       но потом все-таки из вежливости ответила.(Не намеревалась реагировать)

Слово "думать" здесь употреблено в разных значениях:

1) Не думаю (**не считаю**, здесь определённое мнение), чтобы жена догадывалась об измене. - повествование с **оттенком волеизъявления**. (Как и "не хочу, чтобы догадывалась")

2) Сначала я не думала(**не имела мысли**, не размышляла), что должна отреагировать на его маил, но потом все-таки из вежливости ответила. **Повествование без волеизъявления,**  просто сообщение без отношения к нему.

В предложениях изъяснительного типа союз что относит содержание придаточного предложения к сфере повествовательной речи и по этому признаку противостоит союзу чтобы, обслуживающему сферу волеизъявления, а также союзной частице ли, которая указывает на вопросительность (Он спросил, помогут ли мне).
Противопоставление союзов что и чтобы при некоторых условиях может быть ослаблено. В подобных случаях имеет место функциональное тождество этих союзов, проявляющееся в возможности их свободной мены, или варьирования:

Я сомневаюсь, что у него есть эта книга ~ чтобы у него была эта книга; Нет никакой надежды, что погода улучшится ~ чтобы погода улучшилась. Поскольку эта мена осуществляется в плане повествования, а не волеизъявления, союз чтобы здесь должен быть охарактеризован как заместитель союза что.

http://housecomputer.ru/science/teaching_aids/russian_language/russian_grammar/2765-2787.html

Answer (score 2):

Не думаю, чтобы жена догадывалась об измене - это придаточное изъяснительное. Придаточные **с союзом чтобы** указывает на увереность, сомнение.

> Сначала я не думала, что должна отреагировать на его маил, но потом все-таки из вежливости ответила(В этом случае глагол **думал** обозначает процесс речи (придаточная часть — реальный объект).Замена на союз "чтобы" здесь невозможна.

Придаточные с союзом чтобы присоединяются не ко всем словам, нуждающимся в изъяснении, а только к таким, которые выражают сомнение, опасение, различные виды побуждений, модальные состояния. Например: сомневаюсь, чтобы... боюсь, чтобы не... беспокоюсь, чтобы не... приказал, чтобы...; просил, чтобы... просьба, чтобы... хочу, чтобы... нужно, чтобы... и др.

Кроме того, придаточные с союзом чтобы могут употребляться и при других словах, нуждающихся в изъяснении, **если при них есть отрицательная частица не.** Ср.: Я слышал, что она вернулась из Ленинграда; Я не слышал, что она вернулась из Ленинграда; Я не слышал, чтобы она вернулась из Ленинграда. **В последнем примере объект мыслится как возможный, отсюда оттенки сомнения, неуверенности**

Подробно можете ознакомиться здесь:[Сложноподчиненные предложения с придаточными изъяснительными](http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik/slojnopodchinennyie-predlojeniya-pridatochnyim-68394.html)

Answer (score 2):

В СПП с придаточными изъяснительными используется ряд союзов, и у каждого есть своя специализация: ЧТО - нейтральный союз общего значения, КАК обозначает восприятие, ощущение (видел, как...), БУДТО выражает недостоверность (воображает, будто...). Союз ЧТОБЫ требует ирреальной модальности для опорного слова и глагола в форме прошедшего времени (с суффиксом Л). Побуждение. необходимость, возможность, желание, стремление, **сомнение, неуверенность** - вот темы для союза ЧТОБЫ.

1) Не думаю (=сомневаюсь), **чтобы** жена **догадывалась** об измене. Не думаю, **что** жена **догадывается/догадывалась** об измене (нейтральный союз, чувство неуверенности не выражено).

2)Сначала я не думала, что должна отреагировать на его маил, но потом все-таки из вежливости ответила. В этом предложении сложно использовать форму глагола с суффиксом Л, поэтому ЧТОБЫ не подходит.